# Windows service bamboo-agent won't add logon administrator user returning error code 15 on indows server 1709

Tags: powershell, bamboo, windows-server

I am trying to create a Docker container on windows server 1709.  So, first of all, I am building the image on a bamboo agent on windows server 1709 also.  I created the agent and I am trying to run it add an administrator user on the machine, e.g devadmin.

Because 1709 has no gui I tried adding the user through powershell like this,

```
$UserName = "userdomain\user"  
$Password = "Password" 
$Service = "bamboo-agent"  
$Cred = Get-Credential  
$ServerN = $_.ServerName 
$svcD=gwmi win32_service -computername $ServerN -filter "name='$service'" -Credential $cred 

$svcD.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$UserName,$Password,$null,$null,$null)
```

The user would then add successfully returning the code 0.

Then starting the service would result in the error code 15 which means **The service does not have the correct authentication to run on the system.**

At first, I thought this was me entering something incorrectly in PowerShell so then I downloaded windows admin center and tried adding the user again, the user successfully added again but then when I tried to start the machine I would get the same error.

[image: bamboo-agent error]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening I am not sure if I have to install a role or feature to windows server 1709 to allow this.

Comment: If i don't mistake your user need the right to logon as service. I used this script to give a user the logon as service right https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-script-to-add-b005e0f6

Comment: that could be it but gpedit.msc and secpol.msc don't exist on 1709 do you know how to access the local security policy to change this?

Comment: No but you can do it in powershell directly using this script  https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Log-on-as-a-service-11a50893

Comment: cool that worked thanks